# Is there a animal equivalent of "party" (group)?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> The sheep were being chased by a pack of hounds. Finally, both [...]
>   reached a cliff and the sheep, seeing there was no escape, jumped from
>   it.

I checked on Google's dictionary and I think *parties* only applies to humans:

> **party** 
>   a group of people taking part in a particular activity or trip.

Is there an animal equivalent? Or something close to it?

Comment: In "*pack of wolves*" and "*herd of sheep*", the words *pack* and *herd* are called "terms of venery". Since venery is concerned with giving names to collections of animals, we might have investigate how that term itself is defined, to see how it labels these collections in the abstract, and if it uses any special terminology for the abstract collection. Short answer is that "term of venery" is almost always defined as the practice of labeling "*groups* of animals". So your best bet is *group*. Another option is to use the alternative name "*nouns of assembly*" and call them *assemblies*.

Comment: But you can see neither *group* nor *assembly* is specific to animals, and since, then, he latter word Han claim no advantage over the former, it's probably a better idea to go with the more common and more easily-understood *group*.

Comment: Why did you discard *group*? It's there in the question title.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sometimes there's a more specific and apt word. For example, when humans go out adventuring in groups, they're known as *parties* (and if you only used "adventuring group", you'd miss out on that word). Now, I don't think there is a better or more specific word in this case, but never hurts to ask.

Comment: I suppose you could call them a "party" if they're "party animals".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean both the pack of hounds and the herd of sheep, you could simply use *groups*. 
*Finally, both groups(/of animals) reached a cliff and ....*
I think this is perfectly fine.

If your looking other words to describe a particular group of animals then you could check this wikipedia link out.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_terms_of_venery,_by_animal

But, if you really mean to describe two separate group of different animals by a single word, then I think *group* is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only generic expression that may fit all kinds of animals  is ***[animal group](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/animal%20group)***:

> - a group of animals

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=animal%20groups%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canimal%20groups%3B%2Cc0): animal groups

- both animal groups reached a cliff and ...